# App Mobile Multiplataforma com Xamarin

Tags: c#, mobile, arquitetura-de-software, xamarin, mono

#### Cenário

Essa pergunta é mais voltada a arquitetura. Comecei recentemente a aprender Xamarin para desenvolver Apps Mobile, o Xamarin, que até então tem se mostrado bem flexível, tem `bindings` para as API's nativas do Android e iPhone.

---

#### Pergunta(s)

1. Como se dá a arquitetura de uma aplicação no Xamarin com foco em reaproveitamento de código entre as plataformas?
2. Quais partes do App devem ser desenvolvidas para propósito geral e quais devem ser desenvolvidas para uma plataforma em específico?
3. Devo manter Soluções (`solutions`) diferentes para cada projeto de cada plataforma?

---

#### Informações Adicionais

Qualquer informação que possa ser relevante a questão pode ser anexadas a resposta, assim como alguma possível fonte de dados sobre o assunto.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Arquiteturas

As aplicações em Xamarin podem ser criadas basicamente com dois grandes tipos de arquitetura: **nativa** e **em camadas**. Vou explicar melhor:

### Arquiteturas Nativas

Elas permitem você usar a mesma arquitetura que seria usada se estivesse fazendo o aplicativo usando a linguagem nativa da plataforma, de forma padrão. Ela permite trabalhar exatamente como seria feita numa aplicação em *Objective-C* no *iOS* ou em *Java* no *Android*.

A vantagem de se usar essa arquitetura é que é fácil migrar para o Xamarin desta forma. Caso você já conheça a plataforma em questão é só fazer a mesma coisa usando C# ao invés da linguagem nativa. A desvantagem é que você terá uma aplicação presa na plataforma e não fará uso das vantagens de poder se usar apenas uma linguagem em múltiplas plataformas.

### Arquiteturas em Camadas

Elas permitem que sua aplicação possa ter código reutilizável entre plataformas. Basicamente você pode ter algo *simples e proprietário* em que você separa "na mão" uma porção reutilizável de código e todo o resto que depende da plataforma em camadas diferentes. Há formas mais avançadas e organizadas de fazer isso com *MVC* e *MVVM*.

#### *MVC* - Model View Controller

É o modelo que é usado na Web e que pode ser usado com Xamarin e C# . Este modelo de arquitetura é feito inteiramente pelo desenvolvedor com o auxílio de bibliotecas como [MonoCross](http://monocross.net/).

#### *MVVM* -  Model View View-Model

É uma especialização do *MVC* com uma camada a mais cuidando do que pode ser abstraído e com a ligação automática (`binding`) do modelo com a view. É o mesmo modelo de arquitetura que a Microsoft usa no `WPF` - `Windows Presentation Foundation`. Este modelo de arquitetura é feito inteiramente pelo desenvolvedor com o auxílio de bibliotecas como [MvvmCross](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross).

---

## Como escolher o que colocar em cada camada

Há algumas bibliotecas da própria Xamarin que abstraem várias APIs nativas. O uso dessas bibliotecas com uma arquitetura em camadas faz com que você só precise rescrever a camada de visualização para cada plataforma.

- [Xamarin.Mobile](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.mobile) abstrai coisas como a câmera fotográfica, os contatos, o GPS
- [Xamarin.Auth](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.auth) permite fazer autenticação com OAuth 1.0 e 2.0
- [Xamarin.Social](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.social) permite integrar Facebook, Twitter, App.net e Flickr

---

## Devo usar soluções separadas?

A resposta mais simples é não. O melhor é que seja uma solução só com todos os projetos, de forma que os projetos em comum possam ser lidos e carregados de uma só vez. Isso vai facilitar a sua manutenção.

Lembre-se que as bibliotecas comuns não devem usar APIs ou recursos específicos de nenhuma plataforma e preferencialmente deve ser compiladas usando [`Portable Class Libraries`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)